# regex don't change extension

Tags: regex

I'm trying to batch rename a lot of movie files and I've tried to create a regex which works most of the way.

It looks like like this
`^(.*)(19|20\d{2})(.*[^\.mkv|mp4])`

The input is Zootropolis.2016.DK.ENG.1080p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264-DDP
and the result is Zootropolis (2016)P. I'm of course trying to get rid of the last "P".

How can I do that?

Comment: `[^\.mkv|mp4]` doesn't mean what you think, it means *one character except one of those: `.`, `m` `k`, `v`, `|`, `p` or `4`*

Comment: Besides, `(19|20\d{2})` matches `19` or `20` where only `20` must be followed with 2 digits. Put `\d{2}` outside of parentheses to apply for `19`, too.

Comment: While you question seems unclear to me, I think you might try [`^(.*)((?:19|20)\d{2})((?:(?!\.(?:mkv|mp4)).)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/nmXLqP/1).

Comment: **>>**_I'm trying to batch rename_: Are you using any software or have written a program ? And is the format of data consistent ?

Comment: @Rahul I'm using Renamer from Incredible Bee. The format is somewhat consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: 1: initial string, 2: century 3: year 4: extension

```
^(.*)(19|20)(\d{2}).*(\.[^.]*)$
```

Edit: with additional year matching correct as per Wiktor Stribiżew